# How do I use Angular 6 on ChromeOS with Linux?

Tags: angular, google-chrome-os

I can't connect to the Angular server started with `ng serve` from my browser. It just gives me connection refused. Even if I use `--host 0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Start the Angular server with:

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

View it at: http://penguin.linux.test:4200/

The `penguin.linux.test` is essentially `localhost` on your Pixelbook.